# How to update Fabric UI TagPicker suggestions from redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

A Office Fabric UI TagPicker is an input field that shows matching suggestions in a dropdown to what has been typed in. I can fire a saga (via onResolveSuggestions) to get suggestions from the backend. Later that saga fires a succeded action which can then update the redux state. But how does that state change update the TagPicker's suggestions. I would like to specify the piece of state that the TagPicker should be connected to but that doesnt seem to be possible. or? (react,redux,saga newb)

Comment: Connect the component with suggestions using react-redux. You can then use mapStateToProps to pass the part of state down to the component.

Comment: As I said, the state change is acheived. My problem is with the fabric ui tagpicker. How do I point that to the state change. There is no suitable attribute AFAICS?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my method help someone. I understood that `onResolveSuggestions` should definetly return suggestions. I think it's not intended to work with `redux-saga`. But `TagPicker` has `componentRef`.  I saved tagpicker's node and did next:

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { suggestions } = this.props;
        if (!isEqual(suggestions, prevProps.suggestions)) {
            this.tagPicker.updateSuggestions(suggestions, true);
        }
    }
```

[isEqual](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-fast-compare) - example method for compare

`updateSuggestions` - tagpicker's method (`true` - force update)